# Django framework python

Tags: django

I'm making a registration system for students in Django
When the user enters the student number, the system retrieves all the student data.
How can I work in this

```py
def search(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        srch = request.POST['srh']

        if srch:
            match = Regiest_Form.objects.filter(Q(std_name__iexact=srch))

            if match:
                return render(request, 'Regiest_app/search.html', {'sr':match})
            else:
                messages.error(request,'no result')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/search/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'Regiest_app/search.html')
```

Comment: Please be specific about the problem you are facing and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, you're missing a whole part of django's purpose.
Using django's form, you can delegate all your validation to your form.
If no results are found, your access errors using 'form.errors' and 'form.non_field_errors` within your template.

In `forms.py`

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Regiest_Form

class RegisterSearchForm(forms.Form):
   search=forms.Charfield(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        qs=Regiest_Form.objects.filter(Q(std_name__iexact=self.cleaned_data.get('search'))
        if qs.exists():
            self.add_error(field=None,error=forms.ValidationError("No results found"))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
    @property
    def results(self):
        return Regiest_Form.objects.filter(Q(std_name__iexact=self.cleaned_data.get('search'))
```

In your `views.py`

```py
from .forms import RegisterSearchForm
def search(request):
    form = RegisterSearchForm(request.POST) if request.method== 'POST' else RegisterSearchForm()
    if request.method== 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'Regiest_app/search.html',{'sr':forms.results, 'form':form})
    return render(request, 'Regiest_app/search.html',{'form':form})
```